# How to make a learning list of two files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi i want to make a learning list in hadoop so that if i have two files example : positivereview.txt and negativereview.txt and each of this texts has following reviews :

(positivereview.txt)
Review id 1 : Movie seems cool, i really enjoyed it especialy the action part.
Review id 2...
Review id 3... etc..

(negativereview.txt)
Review id 1 :Movie sucks, i watched the details and the action is just fked up.
Review id 2...
Review id 3... etc..

the output from program i want to develop should be something like this (result from both txt files in one file) :

in:2p/2n

morning:7p/3n

movie:5p/2n

that:8p/9n

(p - positivereview.txt 
n- negaivereivew.txt)

Im using this wordcount java program on hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar, but it will just count all the words from both documents, not seperated like i want it..

how should i build that, is there anyway to modify hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.3.jar (from hadoop included library..) so i can make that happen

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you get two output files from WordCount program you ran on pos.txt and neg.txt.

I assume the output file structure is like this

in 2

movie 3

that 6

...

You need to write another MapReduce program(With input as output directory of a previous MapReduce) key-value pair should be something like this

**UPDATE:**

```
   class PosNegMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String s_arr[] = value.toString().split("\\s");
        int val = Integer.parseInt(s_arr[1]);
        context.write(new Text(s_arr[0]), new IntWritable(val));
    }

}

class PosNegReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      ArrayList<IntWritable> arls = new ArrayList<>();
      for( IntWritable val : values){
         arls.add(val);
      }
      if(arls.size()<2)
          arls.add(new IntWritable(0));
      String s = arls.get(0) + "p/" + arls.get(1) + "n" + System.getProperty("line.separator"); //Here, I took liberty that the word must be in both files.
      Text result=new Text(s);
      context.write(key, result);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I think I misunderstood something. So, take look from the first step.

1) The initial files are [posReviews.txt](http://txt.do/dt821) and [negReviews.txt](http://txt.do/dt82r).

2) So, now run WordCount MapReduce on these two files.(Handle the cases like 
punction marks, small and upper case letters etc.)

3) So, from this MapReduce, you will get two files [pos.txt](http://txt.do/dt820) and [neg.txt](http://txt.do/dt82k)

4) Now, [PosNeg.java](http://txt.do/dt82j) & use this [pom.xml](http://txt.do/dt8vo) to build single jar using maven. [Setup Maven for windows](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/). Use Netbeans to get things done smoothly(look at the package name, GroupID and other things while you setup project).

5) You will get a jar containing all the required files with name "PosNeg-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies". Run this jar using command "hadoop jar .../PosNeg-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.ga.posneg.PosNeg input_dir output_dir"

Try this and let me know.

Comment: no actually im trying to get output file like this :

lets say the word "morning" is repeated once in pos.txt file and twice in neg.txt file then output should be :

morning 1pos/2neg

and so on same with other words

Comment: Yes. According to my logic in program, it read both files and the mapper will make <k, v> pair as <morning, <count_from_respective_files>>. So as pos.txt is having morning one time and neg.txt is also having morning once so, reducer will gather <morning, <count_from_pos, count_from_neg>> output will be: key <count_from_pos>p/<count_from_neg>n. Since I didn't test the code, let me know what above code is giving output. I'm going to test it, though.

Comment: First you have to run separate MapReduce for both of the files.

Comment: hi, i firstly made mapreduce both files seperately, and got the outputs result-pos.txt and result-neg.txt, and then i was trying to use your code above to get results, but i get only words and counts just like classic mapreduce wordcount program.., here is my cmd :

yarn jar ../wordcount.jar ../folder-on-which-are-both-txt-files /resultfolder
i tried this too but this one having some errors during the run:
yarn jar ../wordcount.jar ../result-pos.txt ../result-neg.txt /resultfolder 

Here is the full source-code of wordcount.jar goo.gl/DzVR5T
so is the problem on source-code or in cmd ?

Comment: Hi, i think i did everything as you said, the maven code was succesfully compiled, but when i run the jar on my termnial with the command that you provided.. it gives me this error :

http://textuploader.com/drs31

by the way the simple WordCount program is working, so there is no issue on server side or anything like that, what should i do ? thanks

Comment: Hi, I think we need to talk about how you setup your code. Contact me on a Twitter. You can find it in about me. I put it there today. If there is a problem in contacting provide me a way to contact you. Happy to help.

Comment: Hi, this is a follow-up, did you found the solution? Let me know. So I can update the answer for others.